# Conditional Aggregation query not giving correct output

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to find average using conditional aggregation. I have 2 tables in SQL as below

**RentalExtension Table:**

| RentalItemsID | ExtensionDate | ExtensionBy_UserID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 7 | 2020-07-27 | 10 |
| 1 | 2020-07-28 | 7 |

The **user** table contains attributes as listed in select query

```
select UserID, fname, lname, JobTitle,
    (
        select avg(case when ExtensionBy_UserID = 10 then 1.0 else 0 end) as OrderExtended
        from RentalExtensions
        where ExtensionBy_UserID=userID 
    ) as ExtensionRate
from [user]
where userID = 10
```

When I run the query above I get Extension Rate for UserID=10 as 1.00 and UserID=7 as 0.00. This is not correct output. **When I run the query below, it gives correct output of 0.500 for userID=10** and that is what I want the top query to show. If I can get the averages for both users, that would be even better.

```
select avg(case when ExtensionBy_UserID = 10 then 1.0 else 0 end) as OrderExtended
from RentalExtensions
```

Any help with where I am going wrong?

Comment: Not clear, exactly what output are you expecting, can you give a sample?

Comment: The query Gordon provided below works but It doesn't show output for all users. please see the comments under answer.

Comment: I can see why it doesn't work, I'm just not clear what you want. The second query above is not correlated, do you need that result to be correlated? Do you want each user's average to appear in the first query no matter which user you are selecting, or do you want always user `10`, or do you want only the average for the user you are selecting? **Please be clear**

Comment: yes, each users average, regardless of the user I Specify. Currently I have to specify ExtensionBy_UserID = 10 AND UserID =10.  I want all users Average to show in output and not Just 1 particular user.

Comment: So the average of that user out of the total, we don't care the average of any other user?

Comment: So in this Case, Both users will show Average of 0.50 since there are only 2 record. If there were 3 records total, and 2 records for User 10, it would show User 10's ExtensionRate = 0.66 and 0.33 for User 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@GordonLinoff nearly had it right.

**You cannot use an outer reference directly inside a nested query's aggregation function (for reasons that are unclear to me).**

So you need to get that outer reference into the body of the inner query.
We can do this with `CROSS APPLY (VALUES(`

```sql
select
    UserID,
    fname,
    lname,
    JobTitle,
    (select
        avg(case when re.ExtensionBy_UserID = v.userId then 1.0 else 0 end)
      from RentalExtensions re
      cross apply (values (u.userId) ) v(userId)
     ) as ExtensionRate
from [user]
where userID =10
```

---

***EDIT:* You say in a comment that you actually want the whole `user` table.**

So it's better to just use a normal `join`/`group by` setup, with a window aggregate:

```sql
select
    UserID,
    fname,
    lname,
    JobTitle,
    count(*) as CountOfExtenstions,
    count(*) * 1.0 / count(count(*)) over () as ExtensionRate
from [user]
join RentalExtensions re on re.ExtensionBy_UserID = v.userId
group by userID;
```

Comment: Yesss, I just added where userID  in (select distinct ExtensionBy_UserID from RentalExtensions) and its working exactly as I wanted!!!

Comment: @NebelzCheez as you're doing this for all users in the RentalExtensions table, it would be faster and simpler to aggregate the extensions table to get a count per user, then just divide by the total number of rows in that table. That avoids parsing the whole table again and again for each user.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want a correlation clause in the subquery:

```
select u.UserID, u.fname, u.lname, u.JobTitle,
       (select avg(case when re.ExtensionBy_UserID = u.userId then 1.0 else 0 end) as OrderExtended
        from RentalExtensions re
       ) as ExtensionRate
from [user] u
where u.userID = 10;
```

Note that all column aliases are *qualified* meaning that they show the table the column comes from.

Comment: Hey Gordon, setting,  re.ExtensionBy_UserID = u.userId  not showing me result for all ExtensionBy_UserID's.It gives error.  seems like I have to specify e.ExtensionBy_UserID= 10. I also tried where u.userID in (select ExtensionBy_UserID from RentalExtensions) with your query but that's not showing for all ExtensionBy_UserID either. Otherwise Query is working for 1 specific user.

Comment: error I get: Multiple columns are specified in an aggregated expression containing an outer reference. If an expression being aggregated contains an outer reference, then that outer reference must be the only column referenced in the expression.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to jump through so many hoops...

```
SELECT
  u.UserID, u.fname, u.lname, u.JobTitle,
  1.0 * e.ext_count
  /
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM RentalExtensions)
    AS ExtensionRate
FROM
  [user]   u
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT ExtensionBy_UserID AS uid, COUNT(*) AS ext_count
    FROM RentalExtensions
GROUP BY ExtensionBy_UserID
)
  AS e
    ON e.uid = u.userID
```

Edit: changed to give all users who have an extension, as per your comment on another answer.

Comment: Your version Also works, I will study both queries as I am a beginner. Thanks!